# Proper technique to deal with picture resizing

Tags: html, css, overflow, image-resizing

Im working on a little project and i just finished the basic layout of the first section. I want to also make the page phone accessible with `@media` rules. But for now im asking you guys what the proper way is to deal with pictures on the web page when the browser get resized like this.

From this:
[image]

To this (resized (smaller)):
[image]

It just looks bad. Is it possible to make it so it wont resize and just sort of disappear (kinda like overflow:hidden). if so how would i do this?
Which ways would you recommend as professionals?

```css
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/S6uyw4BMUTPHjx4wXg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/S6u9w4BMUTPHh6UVSwiPGQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* colors */
.col-grey {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
/* header section */
html {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 900;
}

header {
  height: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 24px;
  align-items: center;
  height: 2rem;
}

.logo i {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 5px;

}

.navigation span {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.navigation {
  padding-right: 24px
}

/* main-section */
.learn-more-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
}

.learn-more-container img {
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;

}

.learn-more {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #4A4A4A;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.learn-more h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.learn-more p {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.btn-start-here {}


.btn:focus {
  outline:none !important;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  background-color: #595959;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0;
}

.btn-start-here:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 15px grey;
  background-color: black;
}

.btn-start-here:active {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Comar Academy | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- header section -->
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <!-- <img src="#" alt="A picture our logo"> -->
        <i class="fa fa-globe fa-2x"></i>
        <h1><span class="bold">COLMAR</span>ACADEMY</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="navigation">
        <span>On campus</span>
        <span>Online</span>
        <span>For companies</span>
        <span>Sign in</span>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Main-content -->
    <div class="learn-more-container col-grey">
      <img src="./resources/images/banner.jpg" alt="A picture of people sitting on a table studying">
        <div class="learn-more">
          <h1>Learn something <br> new Everyday</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur adipiscining elit.</p>
          <button type="button" name="Start here" class="btn-start-here btn">Start here</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

line 28 is the one with the picture.Thank you very much for every help :D.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like what bootstrap other framework have done. See the link where you can get your desired result.

```
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/
```

Answer (score 0):

so you could try to give the image a

```
max-width: 50%;
height: auto;
```

Or you could try the media rules from bootstrap, there is no reason why they shouldn't work if you follow the steps. See this page for some help.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

The image would size downward, but never be larger than your max-width. If you want to make it disappear, just give the media rules another try, and change it there with..

```
    @media screen and (max-width:480px) {  
        .cupcake img {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i never used bootstrap b4. is there a way so the img doesnt get resized or fully disappears. Meaning maybe wrapping the image in a div and give it a value of `overflow:hidden`? its doesnt work when i try it but i hope you get what im trying to say

Comment: figured it out nvm :D